# GPLv3 modifications without distribution

Tags: licensing, gpl

I'm curious about the boundaries of GPLv3.

I understand you can't distribute a binary of modified GPLv3-licensed code without releasing the source.

I would assume you can modify GPLv3-licensed code, and use it for a company's internal operations, without distributing the source, so long as you didn't distribute the binary.

But I'm especially curious if you can use the modified code within a larger application without distributing the modified source.

That is:

You have X software, and GPLv3' code (where the tick denotes GPLv3 prime, a modified version).

If the binary for GPLv3' is within X, does that count as distribution? Even if it can't be used as a library for some other project Y?

**Clarification**: First, I'd like to say at the outset this is literally a hypothetical. I have not done this, I'm trying to understand the GPL.

Let's talk about Library Z in GPLv3.

If I take Z, modify it to Z', and distribute Z' *as a library for other people's use* I understand the requirements to mean you must distribute the source.

But if I take Z', and don't distribute *it* as a library for others to use but as an internal library to application X (it is compiled within X), then I'm not distributing Z', I'm distributing an application that uses Z'.

Nobody can use Z', just code that relies on Z'. Is *this* a violation of the GPLv3. Basically, does distribution mean any and all code that relies on a modified form of Z, or does it just mean distributing Z' *itself*.

Correct me if I am wrong, but my understanding is that I can compile Z into an application X and not distribute the source of X. It is only when I modify Z to Z' that it becomes an issue.

Comment: Is X being distributed?

Comment: Yes, that's the point of the question. If X is distributed but uses GPLv3', is that a violation. Where X is not a binary of GPLv3'.

I guess what I'm asking is, does distribution mean that if you ship code that uses GPLv3' in any capacity, is that a violation.

Comment: @mas Do you ship X?

Comment: If by ship you mean sell a software product to customers who use it, then yes. I guess I don't get the difference between distribute and ship?

Comment: So you've used GPLed code as part of a closed-source program you're trying to distribute (/sell). In what possible way could this *not* be a violation of the GPL? What do you think the GPL is trying to restrict, if not *exactly this*?

Comment: @Sneftel My understanding is GPL prevents copying a library, modifying it, and distributing it for use by other parties.

I am going to update the question to be more clear

Comment: @Sneftel: Several ways, for example if the GPLed code already exists on the platform where X software runs due to prior distribution by some party other than the developer/distributor of X.  Perhaps the GPLed code is part of the OS, and X makes OS calls through a non-specific interface such as POSIX, such that X would also work on some other OS that contains none of the GPL software.  But it doesn't sound like that is the situation here.

Comment: @mas: Your new final sentence shows you really do not understand the GPL.  In particular, take a close look at the difference between GPL and LGPL.

Comment: @Sneftel: Another way would be if the GPL library were in fact not distributed, it lives on the servers of the X developers, and every copy of X has to "call home" to those servers to use the services of GPL'.  It doesn't sound like that is the situation here, either.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for the responses. I was referring to the OP’s situation.

Comment: @Sneftel Okay, thank you. So my understanding of GPLv3 was completely wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13532034/9691276 Pretty much explains it.